# Isolated-vm: how to set a global variable that uses custom object instance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sandbox

I need to write a small JS evaluator. I was using vm2 so far, but I want to migrate now to isolated-vm since vm2 is not maintained anymore...

My requirements are:

- a global variable `$var` should be accessible, and should be a **Record<string, string | Error>** like.

  - If the user tries to get the value that is a string, the value should be returned.
  - But if the user tries to get the value that is an Error, the `Error` should be thrown...
  - The values are readonly
- `$var` is created when the evaluator is initialized.

To implement the behavior of my `$var` getters I created a class `VariablesWrapper`:

```js
class VariablesWrapper {
  constructor(data: Record<string, unknown>) {
    for (const key in data) {
      Object.defineProperty(this, key, {
        get: () => {
          if (data[key] instanceof Error) {
            throw data[key];
          }
          return data[key];
        },
        set: (_: unknown) => {
          throw Error("You cannot change a variable value.");
        },
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Then during the initialization of my vm, I set the variable `$var` to `new VariablesWrapper(myRecord)`, where myRecord is:

```js
{
   key1: "a value",
   key2: Error("an error")
}
```

But my result is not what I expect when I use the VariablesWrapper:

```js
const isolate = new Isolate({
  memoryLimit: 64,
});
const context = isolate.createContextSync();
const jail = context.global;
jail.setSync("global", jail.derefInto());
jail.setSync("$var", new ExternalCopy(new VariablesWrapper({
   key1: "a value",
   key2: Error("an error")
})).copyInto());
const hostile = isolate.compileScriptSync("$var.key1");
console.log(hostile.runSync(context)); //it prints `undefined`.
```

While if I do not use my Wrapper, it prints the right value:

```js
const isolate = new Isolate({
  memoryLimit: 64,
});
const context = isolate.createContextSync();
const jail = context.global;
jail.setSync("global", jail.derefInto());
jail.setSync("$var", new ExternalCopy({
   key1: "a value",
   key2: Error("an error")
}).copyInto());
const hostile = isolate.compileScriptSync("$var.key1");
console.log(hostile.runSync(context)); //it prints `a value`.
```

It seems my class is not correctly loaded in the isolate context. Do you know how to do? Thanks in advance.